# How to disable "extends" for a php class?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a class like

```
<?php
   class A
   {
      function foo()
      {
        echo "hello from the foo.\n";
      }
   }
?>
```

Now this class can be extended like:

```
class B extends A{
```

I want to disable this feature of `extends` so the `class A` cannot be extended.

Is it possible?  How can I do this?

Comment: `final class A` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Comment: @MarkBaker that should be the answer

Comment: @Nikola - I work on the principle that if I can answer in less characters than a tweet, then it's not worthy of an answer but only of a comment

Comment: @MarkBaker: That is exactly the solution here! :-D

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer was readily available in the manual.

Comment: "off-topic"? no. lmgtfy/dupe worthy? sure.